# Force EBS to respect Dockerrun.aws.json exposed ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Long story short. I'm struggling with setup `Rabbitmq` single instance in EBS. Locally everything works as expected and I'm able to connect to RabbitMQ via 5672 port. When I deploy the image to EBS it seems that the first port from `Dockerrun.aws.json` is auto bound to port 80, therefore the `amqp` is accessible via this port.

Is there any hack which I can apply to correctly bind the port 5672 to 5672 of the ec2 host?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.7.7-management-alpine

ADD rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/
ADD definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/

EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 15672

CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "some-image-name",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [{
            "HostPort": "5672",
            "ContainerPort": "5672"
        },
        {
            "HostPort": "15672",
            "ContainerPort": "15672"
        }
    ],
    "Volumes": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hack for that is very easy. Simply expose random port as the first entry. 
Now other ports are correctly mapped.

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "some-image",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [{
            "HostPort": "80",
            "ContainerPort": "80"
        },
        {
            "HostPort": "5672",
            "ContainerPort": "5672"
        },
        {
            "HostPort": "15672",
            "ContainerPort": "15672"
        }
    ],
    "Volumes": []
}
```

Comment: If I could upvote you a thousand times I would. This is the answer.

Comment: Any other more modern and logical solution for this issue ? :-) This one is working but lexically does not make sense.